# CSS Linear Gradient Angle keywords to degree conversion

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I want to convert `linear-gradient` keywords like `to right` & `to bottom` into `90deg` & `180deg`.

I have only managed to find out 4 keywords values to degrees:

```
const orientationToAngle = new Map<string, string>([
    ['to top', '0deg'],
    ['to right', '90deg'],
    ['to bottom', '180deg'],
    ['to left', '270deg'],
])
```

This is a part of a function that takes in `colors`, `positions`, `orientation`, and `angle` and returns a `linear-gradient`:

```
export const colorsToLinearGradient = (
    colors: string[],
    positions: number[],
    orientation?: string,
    angle?: string
) => {
    const stopStrings = colors.map((color, i) => {
        if (i === 0) return `${color} 0%`
        if (i === colors.length - 1) return `${color} 100%`
        return `${color} ${positions[i]}%`
    })

    const orientationToAngle = new Map<string, string>([
        ['to top', '0deg'],
        ['to right', '90deg'],
        ['to bottom', '180deg'],
        ['to left', '270deg'],
    ])

    const angleValue = angle || orientationToAngle.get(orientation || 'to bottom')
    return `linear-gradient(${angleValue}, ${stopStrings.join(', ')})`
}
```

I need to figure out how to add in the rest of the values like: `to top right`, `to top left`, `to bottom right`, `to bottom left`? I don't know if I'm missing any other keywords.

So would love to know the angle equivalents of such keywords?

Comment: did you find out?

Comment: @JohnR i think so. someone on /r/gamedev helped me out i guess → https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/n2xs41/calculate_degrees_of_linear_gradient_in_canvas/